# Is there any reason to split this into three lines?

Tags: objective-c, code-size

Please pardon the vague title, but I don't know how else to put this question into a brief sentence.

I wrote the following method:

```
- (BOOL) isValueSet {
    return self.myNumberValue.boolValue;
}
```

and one of my co-workers changed it to this:

```
- (BOOL) isValueSet {
    BOOL ret = YES;
    ret = self.myNumberValue.boolValue;
    return ret;
}
```

Now, to my eyes, these do the exact same thing. However, my Junior Programmer eyes are used to looking at Java and JavaScript code, and I don't know the nuances of the Assembly(?) that Objective-C compiles down to. **Is there a benefit that my co-worker added to this method by expanding it out like this?**

Comment: You should just look at the assembly code and compare. My only real complaint with the second rendition is that `ret` is getting set twice. It might be optimized out, but it offers no benefit to do that. I'd change that first line to be just `BOOL ret;`. Frankly, I prefer the first code sample, though.

Comment: The three lines is pointless. Two lines would be good to make debugging easier. `BOOL ret = self.myNumberValue.boolValue; return ret;`. Then you can put a breakpoint on the `return` line and see the value of `ret`.

Answer (score 1):

There are typical two reason to do so:

- Shorter expressions and statements;
- introducing an identifier that can explain the source or purpose of a value;

Personally I would say that none of the above reasons is met here. But it is a stylistic question …

BTW: Personally I reduce such edits. In most cases it is a matter of personal style and in almost every case there is no right or wrong. So there is no reason to change the code of my co-worker. However, many, many developers think that such stylistic questions are important. (They discus in internet, whether a pointer `*` has to be placed with a left-hand space or a right-hand space or both. Very important!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!) Likely they do so, because they have no idea of the important questions of software engineering.